# Trying to perform federated SPARQL queries on OpenLink Virtuoso but throwing error

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore

I am trying to perform federated searches using my locally installed [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (7.2.2.). I try to use the following 2 commands :

```
 grant select on "DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2" to “SPARQL”;

 grant execute on "DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_IMP" to "SPARQL”;
```

but I get the following error:

> `Error 42000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]SR137: Bad user name in GRANT/REVOKE.`

Any suggestions on tackling this error?

Comment: It looks like in the first line you have "smart quotes" in `grant select on "DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2" to “SPARQL”;`  before and after SPARQL, and in the second line, you have one after SPARQL.  Did you perhaps copy and paste those lines from a website or something?  If you correct the quotes, do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I believe @Joshua Taylor got it mostly right in the comments.

Try copying and pasting these --

```
GRANT SELECT ON "DB"."DBA"."SPARQL_SINV_2" TO "SPARQL";

GRANT EXECUTE ON "DB"."DBA"."SPARQL_SINV_IMP" TO "SPARQL";
```

*Virtuoso-specific assistance often comes faster through the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a [confidential OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), makers of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).*

Comment: I can confirm that this still works for Virtuoso 7.2.8